# Axios post request get body from catch?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have post request with api:

```
axios.post('https://api.myapp.com:8000', formData).then(function (response) {
}).catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error)
})
```

I get here response with "xhr" type. In console I see only:

```
Error: Request failed with status code 422
    at createError (createError.js?2d83:16)
    at settle (settle.js?467f:18)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js?b50d:77)
```

I want to do something like `error.data` the push content into my alert bar.

What I tried is:
`error.responseType, error.response, error.responseBody, error.status`, for every of this calls I get simple undefined. Under network in console I see the content like needed.

How can I get content from such response?

Comment: hi can you reproduce the error on jfiddle, and post the link here, sw we can help you resolve it

Comment: No because my api backend is still only local.

Comment: you can still go ahead and create the fiddle, the only catch here is we will always get  a '404' not found error. and that's fine because we are actually interested in retrieving the data portion on the error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found this solution and it works for me:

```
axios.post('https://api.myapp.com:8000', formData).then(response => {
      console.log(response)
}).catch(error => {
      console.log(error.response)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Change you catch statement like the following. I hope it will work.

```
.catch (error) {
  console.log(error);
}
```